# Formula is not Presenting accurate Result

Tags: google-sheets

I have been using below mentioned formula to get the Count, IF there is name/vale in Col"I" then Col"B" will popup a count as available in sheet.

But there is variance in my formula where it is not counting accurately.

I have added a sheet where formula result is available in Col"B" as well as result i'm looking for in col"C".

You help will be appreciated.

Sheet Link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pkner13t93HBjVTEkVFlDpVnVReVwoRSRIcwf1Q7CpY/edit?usp=sharing

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA (if(LEN(I:I),if(row(I:I)=1,"CASE ID",H2&"_"&TEXT(ROW(B:B)-1,"000")),)),500,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Count"; IF(I2:I="",,"OD_"&TEXT(
 COUNTIFS(I2:I, I2:I, ROW(I2:I), "<="&ROW(I2:I)), "000"))})
```

[image]

Comment: player0, Thank you so much. I wish i had same skills.

Comment: player0, Sir i have been facing an issue I want that formula should work from that range H:H not from that H2:H.
Because my data is filling from google form when i add data from google form H2:H becomes H3:H or sometimes data add in row 2  or row 3. So i want to start it as H:H

Comment: Please have a look @player0 I just want that the Formula should start from H:H not from H2:H

Comment: the formula actually starts from H:H because there is a header "count". this formula provided in above answer should be placed in row 1. also you can try to lock it down with INDIRECT - this way it will never become H3:H no matter what you may add or remove:

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA({"Count"; IF(INDIRECT("I2:I")="",,"OD_"&TEXT(
 COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("I2:I"), INDIRECT("I2:I"), ROW(INDIRECT("I2:I")), "<="&ROW(INDIRECT("I2:I"))), "000"))})`